# Problem with WP_User_Query when 'meta_value' is an array

Tags: wp-user-query

I have a problem with listing my users, who have a birthday today (for this instance today is March 3rd).

I've created a custom field 'birth_date' using tutorial [here](https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/add-custom-user-meta-data-wordpress/) with some minor tweaks.

My WP_User_Query doesn't show any users. Here's my code:

```
    $args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'birth_date',
    'meta_value' => array( 'day' => '03', 'month' => '03')
    );

    // The Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    // User Loop
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {


    echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';

    }
    } else {
    echo 'No users found.';
    }
```

Here is var_dump of 'birth_date':

```
    array(1) { [0]=>
    array(3) { 
              ["day"]=> string(2) "03" 
              ["month"]=> string(2) "03" 
              ["year"]=> string(4) "1992" 
              } }
```

I suspect there is a problem with the way I express 'meta_value' in $args, however my knowledge in PHP is very limited.

Comment: You can't save it as an array if you want to reliably query on that data, it needs to be a single yyyy-mm-dd value.

Comment: @Milo I've figure it out, gonna post my solution in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it worked for me:

```
$current_day = date("d");
$current_month = date("m");

$args = array(
'orderby' => 'login',
'order' => 'ASC',
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {

        if ( $user->birth_date['day'] == $current_day &&
             $user->birth_date['month'] == $current_month )

         { echo '<span>' . $user->display_name . '</span>'; }   

    }
}
```